# Function that tells if something is an integer won't work

Tags: r, function, integer, arguments

For some reason my function "isint" will not work for some fractions. Here is the code:

`isint<-function(x){if(x!=round(x)){return(0)}else{return(1)}}`

isint(1.05/1.05) gives me 1 however isint(1040.55/1.05) gives me 0.

Why is this the case?

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).

```
options(digits = 20)
1040.55/1.05
[1] 990.99999999999989
```

Since `991!=990.99999999999989` you get `0`

Answer (score 0):

This is just because arithmetic base-2 is not exact base-10.  A better test would be to use `!all.equal(x,round(x))`, which allows for small discrepancies.  For example, compare the following...

```
> all.equal(1040.55/1.05,991)
[1] TRUE
> identical(1040.55/1.05,991)
[1] FALSE
```

So, try `isint<-function(x){if(!all.equal(x,round(x))){return(0)}else{return(1)}}`